# Dividing Sine Identity

Tags: trigonometry

### Simplify $sin(2x)+2sin(6x)=0$

I don't understand how to solve this, because there doesn't seem to be an applicable sine identity here.

What I tried:

1. $sin(2x)=-2sin(6x)$
2. $2x = A$
3. $sin(A)=-2sin(3A)$
4. $\frac{sin(A)}{sin(3A}=-2$

And then I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: begin by putting X=2x and replace.

Comment: Use $\sin(3A)=3\sin(A)-4\sin^3(A)$. Then set $\sin(A)=t$, to get an equation in $t$.

Answer (score 1):

with $A=2x$,
the equation becomes
$sin(A)+2sin(3A)=0$

but
$sin(3A)=
sin(2A+A)=
sin(2A)cos(A)+cos(2A)sin(A)=
3sin(A)-4sin^3(A)$
which gives

$7sin(A)-8sin^3(A)=0$

thus
$sin(A)=0$ or $cos^2(A)=\frac{1}{8}$

so

$A=k\pi$ and $x=k\frac{\pi}{2}$.

to get the other solution, let $ a$ be such that $ cos(a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$

we will have
$cos(A)=cos(a)$ and 
$x=+,- \frac{a}{2}+k\pi$ or
$cos(A)=-cos(a)=cos(\pi-a)$ and

$x=+,-\frac{\pi-a}{2}+k\pi$.